# SSIS Slow to copy between two tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working on an inherited ETL process that runs on SQL Server 2017 and uses SSIS.

The Package that I'm looking at takes all the data from Table A and simply copies it to Table B. Both are on the same server, though on different DBs.
I've been running this code in order to test out the package before updating it, and after 20 minutes, it's transfered 60k records.

One thing that could be a culprit, though I'm not sure how to fix is that the table names are set through a variable. Does that affect the speed, and could that make much of a difference?

I've checked and neither tables have an index or partition.
The tables themselves are fairly simple. Under 20 fields, largest one is a varchar(50).

Also, I checked the tempdb, looks like it's about 25gigs, 20 gigs for the datafile, 5gigs tempdb.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to debug this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes SSIS does extremely slow buffering if it's running a `select * from` on the database - known bug, it struggles with the metadata.  If you are just selecting the table, it will be running a `select * from` under the hood.  Try running the source extract as a query with the column names listed.  It generally hates anything where you are not explicit with the metadata.

Comment: Is this SQL Server to SQL Server?

Comment: Make sure the OLE DB destination data access mode is set to "table or view - fast load". 50 rows/sec looks like singleton inserts, and slow ones at that. Another possibility is blocking due to concurrent activity.

Comment: What is happening on the target table when you're loading? Are there other processes accessing it? How is the Destination configured? If you replace the destination with say, a Row Count, deploy and re-run it - how long does it take?

Comment: Please include properties of OleDB Destination, to address the issue